# Compare new field value with old before save

Tags: ruby, datamapper

I am building a Ruby Sinatra app with Datamapper as the ORM. I have come across a point that I can't find a decent solution and thought to hit StackOverflow for a solution.

I am needing to compare the old value of a filed with the new value entered by the user to do a small computation.

For example

```
car = Listing.all(type: :car).first
car.price # 200
car.price = 100
car.save  # ~> discount = ( 200 - 100 / 200 ) * 100 ~=  50% - alert watchers
```

How can I find the old value within the modal?

I have an idea to abstract all modals with custom classes. This will make such operation possible. But wonder if it will add complexity unnecessarily.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If You were using Rails.. There is an option. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can pull out the old value via `model.original_attributes`. Something like this should work for your case:

```
car = Listing.all(type: :car).first
car.price = 100
old_price = car.original_attributes[Listing.properties[:price]] # => 200
```

You should be able to put that in a before save hook and run your calculations and notifications from there.

HTH :)

(BTW I tested this with DM 1.2.1. I imagine that is the version you are using as well since the DM project is kind of dead-ish these days, but just so you should be aware)

Comment: I would complement your answer putting this code inside a hook (after save maybe?)

Comment: @rockskull exactly! I used before save in my example but after save probably makes more sense

Comment: Ah looks great. Let me give it a Tey tomorrow morning.